# What are these orange insects under the leaves of my mandevilla?

Tags: identification, pest-control, mandevilla

**First, I'll set the scene:**

Location: South Florida

Temperature: 75°F - 85°F most days

Rain: Had been fairly dry until the last couple days

Affected plant: Mandevilla with yellow flowers

[image: Yellow Mandevilla]

**Story:**

There usually isn't a day that goes by that I don't take a close look at my mandevilla (multiple) in order to guide the vines and such. So, I was surprised to notice this morning these little orange insects on the bottoms of a bunch of leaves that looked like the life was being sucked out of them.

[image: Insect and eggs on removed leaf]

I cut most of the leaves they'd infested and hit the rest of the plants with some high-pressure water to hopefully knock off some of the remaining insects and the little black specs (eggs?) that accompanied them.

After that, I sprayed a combo of water and Dawn soap around the affected areas.

What are these little guys, and what's the best way to keep them in check?

[image: Insect fully grown]

[image: Insects on the Mandevilla]

Comment: I don't know what they are but soap and water at regular (5-6 day) intervals will control them.  Soft bodied insects have no defenses against soap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am no expert about bugs or caterpillars. But still I have a guess: from what I found what you have there *could* be *Oleander Caterpillar* ([Syntomeida epilais at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntomeida_epilais) - however the pictures there did not lead me to this conclusion).

See [here](http://www.ehow.com/info_8647271_wrong-mandevilla-turning-yellow.html) for an article I found which lead me to this [PDF of the University of Florida](http://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/pdffiles/in/in13500.pdf) about these caterpillars. Look at Fig.2 on page 2. The small ones seem to be similar to your pictures.

In this PDF there is also a section about controlling this pest.

Comment: Patrick, I think you're right. Though my picture isn't very sharp, the one of the single insect looks a lot like figure 3.

Comment: I should add that I also read they can be found in Mandevilla.